# Sed using a variable for line number restriction

Tags: bash, sed

I want to do a search and replace on a line with specific line number. However, I want to be able to use a variable for the Line Number itself.

For instance, if I wanted to replace the number 4 with a number 5 on line 180. I would use the following code.

```
sed '180 s/4/5/' file
```

My Question is how do I use a variable for the line number?

```
sed '$variable s/4/5/' file
```

Comment: Just like you did, but with double quotes: `sed "$variable s/4/5/" file`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@gniourf_gniourf's comment contains the crucial pointer: use *double* quotes around your `sed` program in order to reference *shell* variables (the shell doesn't interpret (expand) *single*-quoted strings in any way).

Note that **`sed` programs are their own world** - they have **NO concept of variables**, so the **only way to use variables is to use a *double-quoted string* evaluated by the *shell* containing references to *shell variables***.

As a result, you must `\`-**escape characters that you want the shell to ignore and pass through to `sed` to see**, notably `$` as `\$`.

In your specific case, however, nothing needs escaping.
Thus, as @gniourf_gniourf states in his comment, use:

```
sed "$variable s/4/5/" file
```

---

Afterthought:

Alternatively, the core of your `sed` program can remain **single-quoted**, with only the **shell-variable references *spliced in* as double-quoted strings**; note that *no spaces* are allowed between the string components, as the entire expression must evaluate to a *single* string:

```
sed "$variable"' s/4/5/' file
```

While in this specific case you could get away without the double quotes around the variable reference, it's generally safer to use them, so as to avoid unwanted shell expansions (such as word splitting) that could alter or even break the command.

Answer (score 1):

You could just leave the variable outside of the quotes

```
sed $variable's/4/5/' file
```

Note that there cannot be a space between the variable and beginning quote though

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `awk`

```
awk 'NR==l {sub(/4/,"5")}1' l="$variable" file
```